# Ensure that a partial is full at runtime

Tags: typescript

My function takes argument `meOrPartial` which is typed as `Partial<IMe> | IMe`. In the body of my function I need to detect if it is "full", is there a way to do this at runtime?

I tried this pseudocode (IMe has much more keys than this):

```
interface IMe {
   id: string;
   isActive: boolean;
}

function (meOrPartial: Partial<IMe> | IMe) {
   const meKeys = keyof IMe;
   // const meKeys = K in IMe;
   const isFull = Object.keys(meKeys).every(key => meOrPartial.hasOwnProperty(key));

}
```

Of course this doesn't work, but is there a way to do this check in runtime?

Comment: `| IMe` is not needed, `Partial<IMe>` includes `IMe`. You can compare `Object.keys(meOrPartial)` with the keys of a known complete object (you create for this purpose).

Comment: Thanks @axiac - I was trying to not have to manually create for this purpose, is method available in TS?

Comment: There is no TS when your script runs, only JS. TS cannot help.

Comment: Can you please describe your intention of this check? Object of type `Partial<T>` may have `undefined` value for all of it keys. So if you want all keys not equal to `undefined` just use  `function (meOrPartial: IMe)`. Or you may have cases when `meOrPartial` be either `Partial<IMe` or just `IMe` and you want to have different code paths depending on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript interfaces are not runtime artifacts and so there is not much you can do without also defining some sort of object that contains all the keys you are checking for.

With that in mind, I would do something like this:

```
const MeTemplate: IMe = {
  id: '',
  isActive: false,
  ...
};
```

And then your `isFull` function would look like this:

```
function isFull(obj) {
  return Object.keys(MeTemplate).every(prop => prop in obj);
}
```

It's less than ideal that you need to define the keys of `IMe` twice, but this is mitigated by assigning `MeTemplate` a type of `IMe`. This ensures that if you change the shape of `IMe`, you will have a compiler error until you also change `MeTemplate`.

Comment: This is a sound logic way of avoiding errors when declaring `IMe` twice, thanks.